# Need Help on SQL query script

Tags: sql, db2

New to the site, new to writing SQL queries and have no background in this type of thing.
But I've been googling my way to victory for the most part.

I'm struggling on probably a very simple problem.
I'd like to Sum the contents of a column, if a different value in the row is the same as in another... That was worded horribly - how about an illustration:

```
Input Table

 1.  ID Value 
 2.  1  1000
 3.  11 600
 4.  11 1000
 5.  11 110
 6.  11 300
 7.  3  999
 8.  3  1
 9.  4  500
 10. 4  400
 11. 5  1200
 12. 6  1050
 13. 6  100
```

So basically I'm looking for an output when I run the script that shows 
Value must >= 1000 after sum up with unit ID.Unit ID shown again if first value hit 1000。
The indicator field will shown 'Y' is value is >= 1000.
Expected Output result:

```
 1. ID  Value                 Ind
 2. 1   1000                    Y
 3. 11  1000                    Y
 4. 11  1010 (600+110+300)      N
 5. 3   1000 (999+1)            N
 6. 5   1200                    Y
 7. 6   1150 (1050+100)         Y
```

And various other simplistic queries, but at this point I'm willing to admit that I haven't a clue what I'm doing.

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks!

I have try out with 
 `Select ID,sum(Value) from table group by ID having sum(value)>= 1000` but return me the result below

```
    ID   Sum(Value)
    3       1000
    5       1200    
    1       1100        
   11       2010
    6       1050
```

The Id does not spare 2 line with value 1010 and 1000. Any idea how to spare out?

Have try out SQL advice by Radu Gheorghiu but seen like doesn't work as I expected result.
SQL:

```
Select ID,sum(value),‘N' from table where value >= 1000 group by ID
UNION
Select ID, value,'Y' from table where value >= 1000
```

Output Result:

```
ID SUM(VALUE) Constant Value
5  1200        N
1  1000        N
11 1000        N
6  1000        N
1  1000        Y
11 1000        Y
5  1200        Y
6  1050        Y
```

Thanks Hogan,
Have try out SQL advice by Hogan it but seen doesn't work as I expected result.
The ID 6 element values was no sum up into 1150 with (1050+100)

sql:

```
-- Select items over 1000
SELECT ID, value, 'Y' AS Ind
FROM table
WHERE value >= 1000
UNION ALL
-- Select sum of the other items where total is >= 1000
SELECT ID, SUM(value) AS value, 'N' AS ind
FROM table
WHERE value < 1000
GROUP BY ID
HAVING SUM(value) >= 1000

Output result:
   ID SUM(value) Constant Value
     1 1000       Y       
    11 1000       Y
     5 1200       Y
     6 1050       Y (should be 1150)
     3 1000       N 
    11 1010       N
```

Thanks for Hogan answer.

After review again expected output with my client ,they confirm and come out the new requirement as per below:

```
Input Table:
     1.  ID Value 
     2.  1  20
     3.  1  30
     4.  1  20
     5.  1  30
     6.  1  10
     7.  2  51
     8.  3  50
     9.  4  20
     10. 4  30
     11. 4  10
     12. 4  5
     13. 4  50
     14. 5  5
     15. 5  50
     16. 6  5 
     17. 6  3
     18. 6  50
     19. 7  35
     20. 7  4
```

Any ID aggregated of values >= 50 need to shown and the indicator flag shown as "Y" for only one ID value >= 50.

Expected output :

```
 1.  ID Value                IND
 2.  1  110(20+30+20+30+10)   N
 3.  2  51                    Y  
 4.  3  50                    Y          
 5.  4  115(20+30+10+5+50)    N  
 6.  5  55 (50+5)             N  
 7.  6  58 (50+8)             N
```

Thanks
Any expert can advice ?I don't mind to create another working table to meet my expectation result.

Comment: Why does id 1 get a value of 1100 and no indicator -- I think it should be 1000 and Y

Comment: What makes this hard is "unit id shown again if first value {you mean sum here} hit 1000"

Comment: This problem is clearly not suited for SQL -- it would be much faster in an iterative language.  While possible in a select statement you probably want a cursor.

Comment: What platform are you using?  MySql, MS Server, Oracle, DB2?

Comment: I using DB2 at AS400 platform

Comment: @DumAco Have you tried the query from my latest answer?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu - You latest answer does not return what he shows in rows 1, and 7.

Comment: my suggestion - without a solution - is to look at a LAG function.

Comment: Hi Radu, I had try out your query but seen doesn't work as I expected

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
SELECT  `id` , SUM( value ) AS total, 
CASE 
WHEN value >=1000
THEN  'Y'
ELSE  'N'
END AS YN

FROM  `yourtablename` 
GROUP BY  `id`
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem since the results need to be split. If there are four rows that should be summed up (all with an equal id) and the sum of the first two rows is >= 1000 there has to be at least a second result for the same id.

Comment: You could just determine Y or N as you parse through the results.  You'll already have the values.

Comment: OK... I've reread the question since you've clarified it.  It looks like you want it grouped by that third column.

Comment: This queury does not give the same results as id 11 and 1.

Comment: First part would be to sort out every entry that is >= 1000. After this you need to sum up the other colums. But I can't imagine a simple technique to stop summing up if a defined value is reached.

Comment: Is this mySQL or something else?

Comment: Your Y and N appears to be backwards from what you've described.

Comment: I've edited the query to return what I think you're asking for, but I'm not sure how to have it display the parts in the ()... like (1000 + 110).

Comment: SQL return error format invalid:Column ID or expression in Select list not valid.

Comment: I have to admit, I don't have DB2 sql to test that.  It works fine in mySQL.

Comment: Try using INTO :TOTAL instead of AS Total.

Answer (score 0):

With crazy new requirement:

```
WITH over1000 AS    -- Select items over 1000
(
  SELECT ID, value 
  FROM table
  WHERE value >= 1000
), sumOver1000 AS -- Select sum of the other items where total is >= 1000
(
  SELECT ID, SUM(value) AS value, 'N' AS ind
  FROM table
  WHERE value < 1000
  GROUP BY ID
  HAVING SUM(value) >= 1000
), over1000andOthers AS -- Add in "missed" items
(
  SELECT ID, sum(value) AS value, 'Y' AS ind
  FROM
  (
    SELECT ID, value 
    FROM over1000 
    UNION
    SELECT ID, value 
    FROM table
    WHERE ID in (SELECT ID FROM over1000) -- probably not needed should be in one table or the other.
      AND NOT (ID in (SELECT ID FROM sumOver1000))
  ) sub
)
SELECT * 
FROM over1000andOthers
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM sumOver1000
```

---

First the requirements.  I believe your requirements are the following:

Given a list of ID and Value for each ID

- If there is an element greater than or equal to 1000 output that ID and value with a Y indicator flag
- For all other items sum those items.  If the sum is greater or equal to 1000 then output that ID, sum and a N indicator flag.

Problems with these requirements

- What if there is more than one ID element which is greater than 1000?  For the following I assume there is only one.
- There is no statement of input ordering -- further complicated by a mysterious statement about the indicator being dependent on the "first" item.  I'm ignoring this for now.  If you can explain what makes an item "first" then I can put that in the query.
- Results ordering, does the output ordering matter?
- Your expected result does not match these requirements.  Given the above requirements I would expect your results to be:

  ```
  ID Value Ind
  1  1000  Y     (This shows as 1100 in your example)
  11 1000  Y
  11 1010  N     (This shows as 1100 in your example)
  3  1000  N
  5  1200  Y
  6  1050  Y     (This shows as 1100 in your example)
  ```

I'm going to assume you just made a mistake and what I have above is what you want.

Here is how you do it in DB2

```
-- Select items over 1000
SELECT ID, value, 'Y' AS Ind
FROM table
WHERE value >= 1000
UNION ALL
-- Select sum of the other items where total is >= 1000
SELECT ID, SUM(value) AS value, 'N' AS ind
FROM table
WHERE value < 1000
GROUP BY ID
HAVING SUM(value) >= 1000
```

Comment: Here my requirement. 1)One ID element can be greater than 1000 for safe. 2) Output result no necessary in order,this can be sorted later. 3) My expectation result show be sum out of ID element 1110 (600+300+110) typo error.

Comment: @DumAco 600+300+110 = 1010 not 1110

Comment: I have try your sql, the ID 6 should be shown with 1150 (1050+100).

Comment: @DumAco, This is exactly my question.  Why is ID 6 1150?  1050 is greater than 1000 so just that should be returned according the requirements above.  The only way I see that it isn't if there is an ordering where the summing of values matters and 100 is read before 1050.  If this is the case then you have to say what the requirements are.  As they stand my code above gives the correct results.

Comment: Hi Hogan,based on your earlier understanding,the result are correct but I think you may missed out case Id 6. Sry for my requirement did'nt state clearly, for Id 6 it should 1150 because the one of value at Id 6 is 100 which is not >= 1000, hence need to sum out with value >=1000.

Comment: @DumAco - Why is this working differently than ID 11 -- it has values less than 1000 too.

Comment: Because the remaining value <= 1000 total sum out >= 1000 (600+110+300)=1010,hence it no need group together with 1000.

Comment: @DumAco - those are called CTEs -- they are temporary tables you make on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

R1

```
   A    B   C
   3    1   0
   5    2   3
   5    4   2
   2    6   3
```

Given the table R1 what is the result  ?

```
Select R1.A , count(*) from R1 (select A from R1 GROUP BY A ) R2 where R1.A >= R2.A group by R1.A HAVING COUNT (*) > 1;
```

ng